# How to refresh list of *edited* input source names in macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, input-source

I've upgraded a couple days ago to macOS Mojave and [customized my input source names](https://superuser.com/questions/239313/how-to-change-the-input-source-name-in-mac-os-x), however the new input source names are not being updated in the language switcher (they should have been EN, RO and EΛ):

[image: language switcher on macOS Mojave]

I've double-checked that my changes are indeed where they should be and they are:

```
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /System/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/AppleKeyBoardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings 
Command: Print Romanian-Standard
RO
Command: Print U.S.
EN
Command: Print Greek
ΕΛ
Command:
```

I presume there's a cache involved somewhere that I need to reset, but I don't know where or how. Any ideas?

Comment: @clemsamlang when I was on High Sierra, I didn't have to change the names in those files, those are when the whole UI is in a language other than English. And back then, with High Sierra, it would work just fine after a restart.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me "where" you came from. (Sorry for the disturbance.)

Comment: @clemsamlang don't worry, thanks for trying to help.